# PHP OOP variables from database

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am currently working on a CMS and am learning how to use OOP.

My question is: How do I take variables set in a mysql database and use them on my website?

Lets say I have 2 columns, one called `var_name` and `var_content`.

How would I use it so that `$var->sitetitle;` echos out whatever it matches up to in my database?

I don't know what this is called, if anyone could lead me in the right direction, I appreciate it!

Right now, I have this:

```
require_once("classes/database.class.php");
$database = new database();
$database->set_value('sitevariables', $database_prefix . "sitevariables");
$database->set_value('host', $database_host);
$database->set_value('pass', $database_pass);
$database->set_value('user', $database_user);
$database->set_value('table', $database_table);
```

I wanted it so I could use `$database->host` to get my mysqli server. It's basically the same thing as I want to do, except it takes from the database to get and set the values

Comment: Please show us the code of class database

Comment: You want to read the database connection settings from the database?

Comment: may be you need to build a class that extends the database class to set the varibales as you need. then you can use that object of the class.

Comment: Looks like that the thing you're looking called an *ORM*.

Comment: You **need** database credentials to get data from databases...

Comment: Use PDO please, to connect to the database server, for example: if you have some data structure in your database, you can retrieve data and create proper objects based on this data.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a function to get variables, once your database connection is set up (I sadly not think it is possible to query the database for credentials to connect to that vary database. kind of spiraling thing there.)

this takes into account that `var()` is a member function of your `database()` class. Since I don't have your database class, I don't think the way I'll query the database is like yours, but you will be able to fix that.

```
function var($var_name) {
  $stmt = $this->query('SELECT var_content FROM variables WHERE var_name=?');
  $stmt->execute(array($var_name));
  return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}

$sitetitle = $database->var('sitetitle');
```